# Killing Spark job using command Prompt

Tags: apache-spark

What is the command to kill spark job  from terminal. 
I don't want to kill a running spark job via spark UI

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are running on yarn use

```
yarn application -kill applicationID
```

Get application id from WEB UI or list with `yarn application -list`

```
./bin/spark-class org.apache.spark.deploy.Client kill <master url> <driver ID>
```

or you can look the `spark-submit` id by the command `jps` and kill the process but this is not the suggested way

Answer (score 9):

To see the list of applications that are running

```
yarn application -list
```

to kill

```
yarn application -kill appid
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using yarn then just use below command in the terminal

```
yarn application -kill application_id
```

Answer (score 4):

With below command you will get all running jobs in cluster. Use grep keyword to get exact job and kill the job using that application id. simple and fast.

```
yarn application -appStates RUNNING -list | grep "applicationName"

yarn application -kill <applicationId>
```