# How do you kill a Spark job from the CLI?

Tags: apache-spark

[Killing Spark job using command Prompt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43226855/killing-spark-job-using-command-prompt)

This is the thread that I hoped would answer my question. But all four answers explain how to kill the entire application.

How can I stop a job? Like a count for example?

I can do it from the Spark Web UI by clicking "kill" on the respective job. I suppose it must be possible to list running jobs and interact with them also directly via CLI.

Practically speaking I am working in a Notebook with PySpark on a Glue endpoint. If I kill the application the entire endpoint dies and I have to spin up a new cluster. I just want to stop a job. Cancelling it within the Notebook will just detach synchronization and the job keeps running, blocking any further commands from being executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spark History Server provides [REST API interface](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#rest-api). Unfortunately, it only exposes monitoring capabilities for applications, jobs, stages, etc.

There is also a [REST Submission interface](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/rest/RestSubmissionClient.scala#L39) that provides capabilities to submit, kill and check up on status of the applications. It is undocumented AFAIK, and is only supported on Spark standalone and Mesos clusters, no YARN. (Thats why there is no "kill" link in Jobs UI screen for Spark on YARN, I guess.)

So you can try using that "hidden" API, but if you know your application's Spark UI URL and job id of a job you want to kill, the easier way is something like:

```
$ curl -G http://<Spark-Application-UI-host:port>/jobs/job/kill/?id=<job_id>
```

Since I don't work with Glue I'd be interested to find out myself how its going to react, because the kill normally results in `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job <job_id> cancelled`.

Comment: using curl gives me errors `curl -G <sparkmaster>/app/kill/?id=<app-id>&terminate=true` ==> `Error 405 Method Not Allowed`

Answer (score 1):

building on the answer by [mazaneicha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/638764/mazaneicha) it appears that, for `Spark 2.4.6` in `standalone` mode for jobs submitted in `client` mode, the curl request to kill an app with a known applicationID is

```
curl -d "id=<your_appID>&terminate=true" -X POST <your_spark_master_url>/app/kill/
```

We had a similar problem with people not disconnecting their notebooks from the cluster and hence hogging resources.

We get the list of running applications by parsing the webUI. I'm pretty sure there's less painful ways to manage a Spark cluster..

Answer (score 0):

list the job in linux and kill it.

I would do
  ps -ef |grep spark-submit
if it was started using spark-submit. Get the PID from the output and then
 kill -9

Answer (score -1):

Kill running job by:

1. open `Spark` application UI.
2. Go to `jobs` tab.
3. Find `job` among `running jobs`.
4. Click `kill` link and confirm.

Comment: I explicitely state that I am aware of this option and that I would like to use the CLI.